# Lighttpd: Serve all files in directory as static

Tags: linux, security, webserver, lighttpd

### How can I prevent any code execution under a specific directory path using Lighttpd configuration?

I do not want to use a whitelist/blacklist, but simply serve any file as a static file under that path.

```
$HTTP["url"] =~ "^/static" {
    # STATIC ONLY
}
```

Answer (score 1):

All modules usually have a way to disable what they are doing, for example:

```
cgi.assign = ()
fastcgi.server = ()
scgi.server = ()
proxy.server = ()
```